# Copy Neo4j Desktop Edition DB to cloud

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to get the Paradise Papers running on an AWS cloud server.  I installed Neo4j Desktop on my mac, and commissioned a server by deploying the AMI from https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B071P26C9D.

I then copied the data from the Desktop install to the cloud install, updated the `neo4j.template` file to point to the new directory, and restarted the service.

The problem is that I can no longer connect to the server.  In the log files I can see the following lines (along with a lot of diagnostic information).

```
2018-09-30 07:41:59.920+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.f.CommunityEditionModule] No locking implementation specified, defaulting to 'community'
2018-09-30 07:42:00.104+0000 INFO [o.n.k.AvailabilityGuard] Requirement makes database unavailable: Database available
```

I suspect that there may be some kind of licensing or version constraint that is preventing the database from running.  Could this be possible?  Or is it something else?

Comment: Can you share the all `debug.log` file ? Moreover, what do you mean by `I can no longer connect to the server` ? Can you see the browser ? is it a login/password problem ? You don't have any data ?

Comment: Hi @logisima, I pasted an extract of the log file here https://pastebin.com/nixCGpeq.  (Advertised IP address obscured).  The pattern repeats about every three seconds.  When I try to browse the site, the browser (Chrome or Firefox) says it is unable to connect.  (i.e. Neo4j browser does not load at all).

Comment: I don't see any message that can explained your issue ... weird. Is there something useful in the `neo4j.log` file ? Can you try to start neo4j after after removing all your plugins (apoc) ? Can you try to start Neo4j on an empty database ?

Comment: On AWS, you should open the port for incoming connection.

Comment: Did you cleanly shut down your Desktop DB before copying its data?

Comment: Hi @logisima, Thanks for reminding me about the neo4j.log.  When I checked this, I could clearly see the problem.  Do you want to make your comment an answer, and I can then apply the bounty and add comments on the specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not related with a licensing or version problem.

In your `debug.log`, I don't see any message that can explained your issue.

Is there something useful in the `neo4j.log` file ? 
Can you try to start neo4j after after removing all your plugins (apoc) ? 
Can you try to start Neo4j on an empty database ?

Cheers

Comment: Thanks @logisima, I had forgotten about the neo4j.log.  In there I found a message that it was "unable to obtain lock on store lock file".  Upon investigation I found that I had the wrong permissions on the database directories.